# Java Nio Files.write is not writing to the file?

Tags: java, file-io, nio

I have to write set of strings to my file...i know its very simple...but i have got stuck...i have a file in src folder getting those files through ClassLoader...
it gets me the file...even when writing it doesn't through any error...

```
     ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(path).getFile());
        if(file!=null){
        Path nioPath = Paths.get(file.getPath());
        List<String> aLines = new ArrayList<>();
        aLines .add("Its appending");
        aLines .add("The files using NIO");
        try {
            Files.write(nioPath, aLines, ENCODING, 
              StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
```

When i open i don't see anything...

Comment: You are looking into the correct file?

Comment: Where you run your program in an IDE or on command line?

Comment: @Jens i saw many answer that i need to close the file...or open with write access...but how do i close in NIO ??/

Comment: @Jens in IDE, i refresh the project nothing shows up...interesting thing is (The data which i am writting into file is fake)...the real data(File) used by some program which works fine..till i shutdown the server...once i restart i need to write to file and again run the program....

Comment: Die normaly not run the program in the src folder. so i suggest to search for the file in bin Folder or in other subfolder in your project

Comment: @Jens yes IDE is not showing the content even after content....i exported project and tested its working...thanks for help

Comment: The URL.getFile() method **does not** return a file name.  It returns the path and query portions of the URL, which may contain percent-escapes for the many characters (including spaces) which are not allowed to appear in a URL.  Also, an application resource should not be considered writable;  in fact, if you run from a .jar file, you will find your code fails every time.